# Callling an external nantscript and wait for its exit?

Tags: build, nant, build-script

I am calling an external nant script from another nant script like below.

```
   <target name="doCreateBuild" depends="">
        <nant buildfile="${project::get-base-directory()}\..\BuildScript\buildCreator.build" target="externaldoCreateBuild" />
    </target>
```

The problem is the call to "doCreateBuild" seems to return immediately without waiting for its completion.

How to make the external scrip to run in the same process so as the call will return only after successful build creation.